# create-react-app: Template was precompiled with an older version of Handlebars

Tags: reactjs, npm, handlebars.js, create-react-app

I just installed `create-react-app` package following the instructions on https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app.

After that I've followed the instructions and created a "myapp" app:

```
$ create-react-app --version
1.0.4

$ create-react-app myapp

Creating a new React app in /home/...mydir.../myapp.

Installing packages. This might take a couple minutes.
Installing react-scripts...
```

After the list of installed packages I've got:

```
Success! Created myapp at /home/...mydir.../myapp
Inside that directory, you can run several commands:

  npm start
    Starts the development server.

  npm run build
    Bundles the app into static files for production.

  npm test
    Starts the test runner.

  npm run eject
    Removes this tool and copies build dependencies, configuration files
    and scripts into the app directory. If you do this, you can’t go back!

We suggest that you begin by typing:

  cd myapp
  npm start

Happy hacking!
```

Ok, but when I'm running the server I've got the following message on browser console:

```
Template was precompiled with an older version of Handlebars than the current
runtime. Please update your precompiler to a newer version (>= 4.0.0) or downgrade
your runtime to an older version (>= 2.0.0-beta.1).
```

I've verified the handlebars version :

```
$ npm ls|grep handlebars
  │   │   └─┬ handlebars@4.0.6
```

I've also tried to set the handlebars version on `package.json` under "devDependencies" and "dependencies" but that didn't work.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Please file an issue so somebody can investigate. Maybe some dependency updated and caused this. CRA itself has nothing to do with Handlebars.

Comment: Actually never mind, I just filed this myself: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1589

Comment: In the future please report your Node and npm versions. Otherwise it's much harder to help and reproduce this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in [Code Climate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/code-climate/phgahogocbnfilkegjdpohgkkjgahjgk/related?hl=en) Chrome extension.
If you uninstall it, the error will go away.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I've added some comments on the issue on github.